# Trigger Jenkins job from Airflow

Tags: jenkins, connection, airflow

I am trying to trigger Jenkins job from Airflow. I have added connection details - Host as "https://jenkins.optum.com/abc/". Addded Username, Password and Port details. Connection Id is 'Airflow_Jenkins'. Jenkins Multibranch pipeline job name is 'Airflow_Audit. When I try to run the task getting below error:

> [2020-04-08 11:41:25,535] {logging_mixin.py:95} INFO - [2020-04-08 11:41:25,535] {jenkins_hook.py:44} INFO - Trying to connect to http://https://jenkins.optum.com/abc/:80
>   [2020-04-08 11:41:25,540] {**init**.py:1580} ERROR - HTTPConnectionPool(host='https', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /jenkins.optum.com/abc/:80/crumbIssuer/api/json (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',))

Below is my code:

```
job_trigger = JenkinsJobTriggerOperator(
  dag=dag,
  task_id="trigger_job",
  job_name="Airflow_Audit",
  #parameters={"first_parameter":"a_value", "second_parameter":"18"},
  #parameters="resources/paremeter.json", You can also pass a path to a json file containing your param
  jenkins_connection_id="Airflow_Jenkins" #The connection must be configured first
)
```

Comment: "Name or service not known" — it looks like DNS-level problems. You have something strange with URLs: "http\://https\:// …" looks weird. And I see host='https', probably here is the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem yesterday. You have to remove the https:// from host. It should be: "jenkins.optum.com/abc/" and in the extra parameter you have to add true, that will indicate that you want to use https according to the documentation: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.8/_modules/airflow/contrib/hooks/jenkins_hook.html